# How do I put a splash screen during shutdown?

Tags: init-script

I'm able to put a splash screen on startup. As soon as powered on, a splash screen is shown till `startx` command is run.

I edited the script to put the same image (for now) while rebooting/halting. I want it to be shown from right after `reboot` command is given, to the time that PC is exactly powered off.

Right now, image is shown right after `reboot` command is given, displayed for a few seconds, then a `tty` is displayed, and the following is written on the screen:

```
map: vt01 => fb0 

raspbian ...
Raspberry login: map: vt01 => fb0 
Oops: Terminated
```

Here is the `/etc/init.d/asplashscreen` script:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          asplashscreen
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop: $all
# Should-Start:
# Default-Start:     S
# Default-Stop: 0 6 
# Short-Description: Show custom splashscreen
# Description:       Show custom splashscreen
### END INIT INFO


do_start () {

    /usr/bin/fbi -T 1 -noverbose -a /etc/splash.png    
    exit 0
}

do_stop () {

    /usr/bin/fbi -T 1 -noverbose -a /etc/splash.png
    exit 0
}

case "$1" in
  start|"")
    do_start
    ;;
  restart|reload|force-reload)
    echo "Error: argument '$1' not supported" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
  stop)
    do_stop 
    ;;
  status)
    exit 0
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: asplashscreen [start|stop]" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac

:
```

I installed this script via `sudo insserv asplashscreen` command.

> How can I make this script run very first on reboot and stay till power off?

Comment: Why did you delete your answer? Did it not work?

Comment: I guess it was a false alarm so I might have deleted the answer. I think I'll need the very same operation within a month, so I could fix the answer at that time.

Comment: Do you mean a false positive (i.e. it did not work)?

Comment: Yes, it was a false positive, it didn't work as intended.